# small cocooned caterpillar found on bathroom door - what is this creature?

Tags: zoology, entomology

[image: small cocooned caterpillar]

This larvae / moth has what seems to be a smooth gray cocoon which looks like a piece of cement. It can carry this cocoon with it as it crawls, and it can come out from both ends of this cocoon.
Would really be interested of knowing what this creature is and how it ended up in my bathroom.

Cheers!

As asked my location is Israel (Mediterranean climate)

Comment: You need to provide your location for species-identification questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/identify-this-smooth-cocoon-worm-from-southern-india)

Comment: I live in South Aftica and suddenly have hundreds of these in my house. They seem to be nocturnal Would love to know what they are