# What is this larva/insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What is this larva/insect that I saw crawling on one of my books?

[image: Image of insect]

[image: Image for scale]

It moves by wriggling motion and seems to be able to retract it's head(?) when disturbed. It is about 8mm long.

Location: Chennai, TamilNadu, South India

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/identify-this-smooth-cocoon-worm-from-southern-india)

Comment: @tyersome While the question is the same I'm not satisfied with the answer given. The larva mentioned in the answer has a white body. This one has alternating white and black stripes. Moreover this larva has two small protruding structures that arise from its head while the one in the answer doesn't. I would like to know the exact species of this larva. If they are just different developmental stages of the same larve then please correct me.